# Using the “Combining Enclosing Circle” character in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, unicode, combine

Is there a way to use the “Combining Enclosing Circle” UNICODE character (U+20DD) together with some other character in Word 2010 to actually form a circled character? There are glyphs for e.g. circled digit one (“①”), but I need circled Latin capital letter A.

Comment: Do you just want Ⓐ U+24B6 ? Unicode has quite a lot of pre-circled characters, even ㊝ ☺

Comment: Yeah, that's it :-) I din't find it my current font. However, my question is a but more general, whether Word has such advanced UNICODE capabilities. I suppose not, unfortunatelly.

Comment: Word actually has quite good Unicode support, especially in the more recent versions. Font support for such characters is more spotty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One trick to do this is to adjust the tracking. In Word (2007), you can highlight the two adjacent glyphs, go into the Font dialog, choose the `character spacing` tab, set "spacing" to "condensed" and "by" field to something such as 10pt. Check the preview for alignment.

This essentially sets the spacing between the two glyphs to a negative amount, causing the second one to overlap the first one. If you change the typeface or size, you will need to tweak it.

Comment: Good workaround :-)

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a font problem. Testing with web browsers produces similar problems as attempts at using U+20DD in Word. Typically, if a font contains it, it is not really implemented as a combining mark in the font but more or less as a spacing character – instead of “?” in a circle, you get just a “?” followed by a circle.

[Font support to U+20DD](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20dd/fontsupport.htm) is limited but contains some fonts where it is implemented as a combining character, at least Code2000, GNU FreeFont fonts (e.g., FreeSans), STIX fonts, Symbola, and XITS. In some other fonts, such as Cambria, there has been an effort on making U+20DD combining, but it has failed (the circle is badly misplaced relative to the base character).

Unfortunately, in the fonts tested, the circle mostly tends to be too small for “?”, but the technique would work for smaller characters, though the results really vary by font and by character. Below is an encircled “?” and an encircled “à” in the FreeSerif font (of the [GNU FreeFonts](http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/freefont/) set):

[image: Sample characters in circle]

Answer (score 3):

There were already codepoints for enclosed A:

- ## [U+24B6 Ⓐ](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/24b6/index.htm)
- ## [U+1F150](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f150/index.htm)

You can find more here

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enclosed_Alphanumerics
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enclosed_Alphanumeric_Supplement

---

However **MS Word has the ability to enclose any character in a circle**. Just select the character(s) you want and then click the *"Enclose characters" button* in the font group. It can not only enclose in a circle but also square, diamond and triangle with at most 2 characters per shape

[image: enclose]

The button will be available on systems with Japanese locale or keyboard. If you don't have any of that you'll need to add the button manually by *right clicking on the ribbon > Customize the ribbon > All commands > Enclosed Characters...*

[image: Ribbon customization]

See [East Asian Text Formatting Features in Office 2010](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/office_global_experience/2010/03/30/east-asian-text-formatting-features-in-office-2010/)

You can also do further customization with the output by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> and edit the field code

Comment: Wow, interesting! Which font do you use? I tried the default Calibri, and the circle won't surround the character correctly—actually overwrites a portion of the glyph.

Comment: I use the default font and choose Enlarge symbol. But the default font in my work PC is probably not Calibri

Comment: Great answer -- this helped me. Thank you.