# How to create circles with number inside in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I am creating a training document using MS Word 2010 and I want to use an arrow to point to a field on the screenshot and apply a number in a circle that corresponds to a table that describes the field.

I can do the arrow but I don't know how to create the numbered circle. Once the arrow and circle are created, I will group them together for that field. Can anyone provide the how to for the numbered circle

Comment: What you're asking isn't really clear.  Is there an example you can point us to, or draw it with crayons on a napkin and scan it?

Comment: [ScreenShot Captor](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Mouser/screenshotcaptor/index.html) can do that and much more. http://i.imgur.com/dIL7l91.png

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're trying to do, you should be able to right-click the circle and select either `Add Text` or `Edit Text` (whichever is available in Word 2010; I'm working with Word 2013 right now) to put the number in there:

[image]
<sub>*(click to enlarge)*</sub>

You can then adjust the text formatting just as if the circle were a regular text box.

Answer (score 1):

You can use special characters named "Enclosed Alphanumerics". Copy an paste to word.
http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/2460-24FF

Comment: So how do I add 22 in a circle? Or anything above 20 or less than 1

Comment: some examples above 20: ㉑㉒㉓㉔㉕㉖㉗㉘㉙ or less than 1: ⓪

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve that

## Use Unicode enclosed characters

The number of different possibilities is limited, but it works

- ## ①②③④⑤⑥⑦⑧⑨⑩⓪⑪⑫⑬⑭⑮⑯⑰⑱⑲⑳
- ## ⓵⓶⓷⓸⓹⓺⓻⓼⓽⓾⓿⓫⓬⓭⓮⓯⓰⓱⓲⓳⓴
- ## ㉑㉒㉓㉔㉕㉖㉗㉘㉙㉚㉛㉜㉝㉞㉟㊱㊲㊳㊴㊵㊶㊷㊸㊹㊺㊻㊼㊽㊾㊿

More about them:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enclosed_Alphanumerics
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enclosed_Alphanumeric_Supplement
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enclosed_CJK_Letters_and_Months

## Use MS Word's built-in enclosing feature

[image: Word enclose characters feature]

It's included in [East Asian Text Formatting Feature](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/office_global_experience/2010/03/30/east-asian-text-formatting-features-in-office-2010/) and works for at most 2 letters (which is fine for up to 99). If you want to enter arbitrarily long text then insert a shape then edit its text like in hBy2Py's answer

For more information about it and how to enable it if you don't see the button you can read [Using the “Combining Enclosing Circle” character in Word](https://superuser.com/q/312966/241386)

Answer (score 0):

For doing such a task I use [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/de/) which is freely available.

1. Draw a circle (<kbd>F5</kbd>) (Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and drag)
2. Double-click **Fill** at the bottom to set the color to **No paint**
3. Click on **Stroke paint** and choose **Flat color**
4. Use 0, 0, 0 for black circle
5. Click on **Stroke style** and choose a width of **0,5** mm.
6. Press <kbd>3</kbd> to center the view on the selected object.
7. Use the Create and edit text objects tool (<kbd>F8</kbd>) to write the number
8. Choose a decent font size so the number fits into the circle
9. Use the Select and transform objects tool (<kbd>F1</kbd>) to select both the number and the the circle

   [image: Align and Distribute tool]
10. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> for the Align and Distribute tool. Choose Relative to: **Last selected**. Press **Center on vertical axis** and **Center on horizontal axis**.
11. Looking good. Now export this to Word.

    [image: Voilà]

Comment: That's overkill. There are simpler ways built into Word